# Write JSONObject in java

Tags: java, json

So I am inserting java string in JSON Object and then writing the JSON object to a .json file

```
cassObj.put("revision", "local/validation-notest");
```

But when I open the json file it shows escape key for that value

```
{"revision":"local\/validation-notest"}
```

Is there a way I can fix that? The desired output is

```
{"revision":"local/validation-notest"}
```

Comment: They are equivalent. You can escape any character in JSON (some you must).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Actually, if my reading of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) is correct, there are only certain characters that can be escaped (though any character can be written using its Unicode code point as `\uxxxx`). Not sure why `\/` is an option, but yeah, it is equivalent to `/`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I'm reading [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#page-8), seemingly more recent, version. It states _Any character may be escaped_.

Comment: Hm. That seems ambiguous, given that the formal grammar a bit further down gives a list of escapable characters. Also, `JSON.parse('"\\a"')` gives `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Yeah, I don't know anymore.